# Multi threading average cost per operation

Tags: c, multithreading

I am learning to write multithreaded programs in c and I just noticed that as I increase the number of iterations for a given thread, the cost per operation goes down.

For example if I have 2 threads and each one adds a number to a global variable and then subtracts the same number, if each thread does this 1000 times lets say, the cost per operation is much higher compared with if each thread does this 1000000 times. Why is this ?

```
static int num_iterations = 1;
int opt_yield=0;

    void add(long long *pointer, long long value) {
        long long sum = *pointer + value;
        if (opt_yield)
            pthread_yield();
        *pointer = sum;
    }


struct arg_struct {
  long long counter;
  long long value;
};



void *aux_add(void *arguments)
{

  struct arg_struct *args = arguments;
  int i=0;
  for (i=0;i<num_iterations;i++)
  {
    args->value = 1;
    add(&args->counter,args->value);
    args->value = -1;
    add(&args->counter,args->value);
  }
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  printf("\n\n");
  int num_threads = 2;

  pthread_t t[num_threads];


struct arg_struct args;
args.counter = 0;



int count=0;
for(count=0;count<num_threads;count++)
{
  if( pthread_create(&threads[count],NULL,&aux_add, (void *) &args) !=0)
    exit();
}



for(count=0;count<num_threads;count++)
{
  pthread_join(threads[count], NULL);
}


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does each thread change own gloabl variable or they use the same global variable? Do you use some sync objects (like mutex)? Or maybe your global variable is atomic type? Could you please post your code?

Comment: Please show the code you used to test this.

Comment: I am not using any synchronization methods as of now because my goal was actually to investigate the race conditions and understand how they work.

Comment: FIne.  Please show the code you used to test this.

Comment: You see, the thing is, we get a lot of students who rephrase their homework questions into a form that suggests that they have actually seen some problem or issue.  They then ask for help/explanations, hoping that SO contributors will then write out their entire homework answer.  There is also a problem with members of voting rings who 'seed' SO with well-known, easy-to-answer, questions for their friends to fill in for upvoting.  I'm sure that you don't want to be seen as belonging to such sets of immoral miscreants, so please post the code that you used to time the thread operation/s:)

Comment: Martin, a stripped down version of my code have been added. Problem is that my code is kind of larger than this with many components, and I would not want to post the whole thing here.

Answer (score 3):

Simply because *creation* and *destruction* of threads is not for free - It takes an overhead in the OS. The more time your thread consumes *actually working*, the less in relation the overhead (which is constant) applies to your overall run time.